# PHP MAIL FUNCTION - SENDMAIL MTA - UBUNTU - ERROR

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, sendmail

Last night I attempt to send emails from my ubuntu server to an address. I used the php's mail function with sendmail MTA and I managed to send some emails. At the beginning I send one email and then it wasn't working. I examined the configurations, if the sendmail MTA is running, port-forwarding...but all these was right. What I did was to uninstall the sendmail and all packages comes with it and then reinstall again. I tried to send and it was working properly. For testing I sent 3 emails and I received them. Today I open my server, try to send and nothing is delivered in my email address. Does somebody have an idea  of what is the main problem of this?

Answer (score 0):

Restart sendmail.

```
service sendmail restart
```

Then try to send the email again.
Did this work for you?